# what shell would you recommend using on mac?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, command-line

I'm new to Mac (using Mavericks)

i thought to install zsh.

Do anyone has a recommendation for a useful shell for mac?

Comment: What special features are you looking for?

Comment: What are you looking for from a shell: portability, performance, extensibility, number of functions, specific key functions, efficiency, security…?

Comment: By the way, as of [macOS Catalina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina), the [default shell is *zsh*](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050).

Answer (score 2):

I use [fish](http://fishshell.com/). It has a lot of functions which make using the terminal quicker and more efficient.

- auto suggestions
- scripting
- command completion
- color

Answer (score 0):

Every shell is useful in its own way. The best shell for you is the shell you have the most experience with and feel the most comfort to use.

So if you have experience with ksh install and use it. If you are used to zsh install it.

Comment: I don't agree with your attitude. It means I'll always stay with the only shell I know, not being exposed to new tools. The whole point of my question was to be exposed and **get used** to new shell

Comment: @EladBenda my attitude is based on your question. You never mention that you want to learn a new shell neither do you mention which shells you do have experience. Furthermore there  is no **best** shell. It really depends what you want to do. And again you did not mention anything you need.

Comment: I didn't mentioned I **don't** want to learn a new shell. It's obvious that there is no **best** as it's all subjective. But I was looking for recommendations.I didn't mention anything as I'm open minded to all suggestions